# iReport: Getting "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" message when add the new datasource

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, java

I don't know what problem with my *JasperReports* report, when I try to add new datasource in *iReport*, I got this error

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 
(unable to load class com.foundation.service.datasource.JsDataSourceService).
```

I followed all the answer on StackOverflow, and I changed the complicance level to 1.7, jre also is set to jre7 too, I already check the environment variable

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25,
```

but still got this error. Please help me to fix that!

Comment: Are you talking about *iReport* or about the *Java* code?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about iReport

Comment: The *iReport* is a *NetBeans* (if you are not using the old "Classical" version). You should check the *JDK* version of your *IDE*. You can find more info reading [Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10382929/876298) post

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also - I had recently installed JDK 7, which is what that incompatible class version is.  The root cause for me was that I was compiling my jasper reports using the maven plugin, which does not have a way to set -target 1.6.  So, my solution was to run maven from a shell in which I'd made the following change:

export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home

do mvn --version to confirm you now get a 1.6 Javac instead of the 1.7.  That's a more brute force way of setting the target class format.

I'm on OS X 10.8 - if you aren't, you may have to change that slightly, but hopefully the idea helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your environment variable is already correct/set to jdk1.7.0_25.
I bet the issue is with your IDE.

If you're using Eclipse, go to **Configure Build Path**

1. Edit existing JRE System Library (previously set to jdk1.6)
2. Choose Alternate JRE
3. Browse to Installed JREs... (normally in C:/Program Files/Java..)
4. Click Finish

[image]